# How to add strings to a list?

Tags: python

So i'm trying to add strings of binary to a list but instead, i'm adding each individual character. I'm a new to python so i'm not quite sure how to do this myself(also, when getting the strings I need to ignore the spaces in between each string of binary)

```
str_msg = "This is a message!"
final = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in str_msg)
print(final)
```

which gives:

> 1010100 1101000 1101001 1110011 100000 1101001 1110011 100000 1100001 100000 
>     1101101 1100101 1110011 1110011 1100001 1100111 1100101 100001

but I then try to create the list this way:

```
binlist = []
for value in final:
    binlist.append(value)
print(binlist)
```

I get:

```html
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', ' ', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', ' ', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', ' ', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '1', '1', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1', ' ', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', ' ', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', ' ', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', ' ', '1', '1', '0', '1', '1', '0', '1', ' ', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', ' ', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', ' ', '1', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', ' ', '1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', ' ', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1', ' ', '1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '0', '1', ' ', '1', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1']
```

Comment: Are you after: `final = [format(ord(x), 'b') for x in str_msg]` ? (you might also want to make that `08b` (or similar) to keep formatting consistent if needed)

Comment: For the second example, please print the output it gives and your desired output

Comment: yes I am after that

Comment: if you use spaces as separator, you can split `final` by spaces to get your list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression:

```
' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in str_msg)
```

is using a generator expression to yield each character in the string: `str_msg` converted to its ASCII value, represented in binary which is then getting passed into the `.join` method of the string `' '` (a space). As a result, you get a space-separated string of the binary representation of that string.

From the sounds of it, you want a `list` of strings containing the binary representation of each character.

This can be achieved with a list-comprehension which has the same syntax as a generator expression, but uses square brackets:

```
[format(ord(x), 'b') for x in str_msg]
```

Answer (score 2):

As said above:

```
str_msg = "This is a message!"
final = ' '.join(format(ord(x), 'b') for x in str_msg)
print(final.split())
```

output:

```
['1010100', '1101000', '1101001', '1110011', '100000', '1101001', '1110011', '100000', '1100001', '100000', '1101101', '1100101', '1110011', '1110011', '1100001', '1100111', '1100101', '100001']
```

### list comprehension

```
str_msg = [format(ord(ch),'b') for ch in "this is a message"]
print(str_msg)
```

output

```
['1110100', '1101000', '1101001', '1110011', '100000', '1101001', '1110011', '100000', '1100001', '100000', '1101101', '1100101', '1110011', '1110011', '1100001', '1100111', '1100101']
```

### map

```
str_msg = list(map(lambda x: format(ord(x), 'b'), 'this is a message'))
print(str_msg)
```

output

```
['1110100', '1101000', '1101001', '1110011', '100000', '1101001', '1110011', '100000', '1100001', '100000', '1101101', '1100101', '1110011', '1110011', '1100001', '1100111', '1100101']
```

Answer (score 1):

You just want to split the string by spaces.
On your final variable,

```
'1010100 1101000 1101001 1110011 100000 1101001 1110011 100000 1100001 100000 1101101 1100101 1110011 1110011 1100001 1100111 1100101 100001'
```

do, `final = final.split()` and you will get your list

```
['1010100', '1101000', '1101001', '1110011', '100000', '1101001', '1110011', '100000', '1100001', '100000', '1101101', '1100101', '1110011', '1110011', '1100001', '1100111', '1100101', '100001']
```

Answer (score 0):

So while all of the answers i've gotten are vaild, I've choosen to accept @Joe Iddon 's answer since it is the answer that gives me the most optimal code(i.e. the shortest).

Thanks to everybody who helped with the question!